# The command did not complete successfully. Perspective org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui.cvsPerspective cannot be found

Tags: eclipse

I cannot found cvs perspective,when I click in open perspective.Please tell me the step to add cvs perspective.

Comment: What version of Eclipse (release and package)? For example: "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Mars release."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CVS is not really recommended any more it is not included in most Eclipse builds.

You can install it using 'Help > Install New Software'. Choose your main Eclipse location in the 'Work with' field and search for 'Eclipse CVS Client'.